# Is there a way to define a default value to be selected in an HTML Form of Radio Buttons?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

```
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="10"/> $10&#8194 
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="25"/> $25&#8194 
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="50"/> $50&#8194
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="100"/> $100&#8194
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="250"/> $250&#8194
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="other"/> Other
  </form>
</body>
```

To make the $50 option the default selection what HTML code would I use?

[Link to code bin demo](http://jsbin.com/uqupet/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just set it as checked:

```
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="10"/> $10&#8194 
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="25"/> $25&#8194 
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="50" checked="checked" /> $50&#8194
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="100"/> $100&#8194
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="250"/> $250&#8194
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="other"/> Other
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just simply add

```
checked="checked"
```

in a declaration of button which you want to be default checked.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="50" checked="checked"/>
```

Comment: I voted this up before I checked it works. Doesn't seem to work for me :-\ I know the selected method is used for having a pre-selected item in a drop-down list… [demo code](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select3)  Documentation [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: yes - I answered, then tried it, and realised I was thinking select, not radio, so edited it to checked.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add "checked":

```
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="50" checked />
```